why "pagefault interrupt" can't use RET instruction?
I'm learning IDT table in ia-32 protected mode.
I created an IDT discriptor and triggered a pagefault interrupt (0xe), the program running normal.
But if I added a RET instruction into code of int 0xe, the vmware virtual machine will report an fault :"VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vcpu-0)"
Pagefault equivalent to int 0xe softinterrupt, why i can't use RET instruction in it to return to the previous code? There is no problem to use int 0xe alone.
The following is my code...
Grateful!
org 0x7c00

flatcode equ 0x0008
flatdata equ 0x0010
flatstack equ 0x0010


section .text

[bits 16]

bsp16:

    cli

    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax

    lgdt [GDT_DESC]
    lidt [IDT_DESC]

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,pagedir      
    mov di,00001000h
    mov cx,pagedir_end - pagedir        
    cld     
    rep movsb

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,page_l2_0        
    mov di,00002000h
    mov cx,page_l2_end - page_l2_0      
    cld     
    rep movsb

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,int0             ;transport int 0
    mov di,0000a000h
    mov cx,int0_end - int0      
    cld     
    rep movsb

    mov ax,0
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov si,int0xe               ;transport int 0xe
    mov di,0000b000h
    mov cx,int0xe_end - int0xe      
    cld     
    rep movsb

    in al,92h
    or al,00000010b
    out 92h,al

    mov eax,00001000h
    mov cr3,eax

    mov eax,80000001h
    mov cr0,eax

    jmp dword flatcode:bsp32

[bits 32]

bsp32:

    mov ax,flatstack
    mov ss,ax
    mov esp,0x2fff

    int 0h                    ;int 0x0

    mov byte [0x6000],'a'     ;pagefault interrupt!

halt:mov byte [0xa00],'r'
    mov byte [0xa02],'e'
    mov byte [0xa04],'t'

    hlt

int0:

    mov ax,flatdata
    mov ds,ax

    mov byte [0xa0],'I'
    mov byte [0xa2],'n'
    mov byte [0xa4],'t'
    mov byte [0xa6],' '
    mov byte [0xa8],'0'

    ret

int0_end:

int0xe:

    mov ax,flatdata
    mov ds,ax

    mov byte [0x0],'P'
    mov byte [0x1],0fh
    mov byte [0x2],'a'
    mov byte [0x3],0fh
    mov byte [0x4],'g'
    mov byte [0x5],0fh
    mov byte [0x6],'e'
    mov byte [0x7],0fh
    mov byte [0x8],'F'
    mov byte [0xa],'a'
    mov byte [0xc],'u'
    mov byte [0xe],'l'
    mov byte [0x10],'t'

    ;jmp dword flatcode:halt  ---> OK
    ret                       ---> problem

int0xe_end:

pagedir:

    dd 00002001h            ;page-directory-table

pagedir_end:

page_l2_0:

    dd 000b8001h            ;text mode 80x25

page_l2_1:

    dd 0000a001h            ;int 0h

page_l2_2:

    dd 0000f001h            ;stack

page_l2_3:

    dd 0000b001h            ;int 0xe

page_l2_4:

    dd 00000000h

page_l2_5:

    dd 00000000h

page_l2_6:

    dd 00000000h

page_l2_7:

    dd 00007001h            ;bsp32

page_l2_end:

GDT:

    dq 0000000000000000h

GDT_CODE:

    dq 00cf9a000000ffffh

GDT_DATA:

    dq 00cf92000000ffffh

GDT_END:

GDT_DESC:

    dw GDT_END - GDT - 1        ;GDTR register value 32(addr)+16(limit)
    dd GDT

IDT:

    dq 00008e0000081000h        ;Interrupt discriptor table
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h                       ;idt-discriptor stored a selector and a offset address.
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 0h
    dq 00008e0000083000h        ;int 0xe

IDT_END:

IDT_DESC:

    dw IDT_END - IDT - 1            ;IDTR register value 32(addr)+16(limit)
    dd IDT

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

db 0x55
db 0xaa


ret returns to a point of a caller but that caller uses something like the call instruction which simply pushes the return address on the stack. ret will pop that return address and return to it. You need iret to return from an interrupt/eception handler because an int instruction in protected mode running in ring 0 (kernel) will push eflags, cs, and eip. iret will restore all those values. Your int0 handler also needs an iret to properly return as well.

Note. Some exceptions raised by the processor (like a page fault) also push an error code on the stack after the return address. In those cases you have to do an add esp, 4 (or equivalent instruction) to remove that value from the stack just before the iret. This chart lists those exceptions which have an error code that has to be removed before you do the iret. Also be aware if a well behaved exception and interrupt handler that modify registers should save and restore them within the handler.When you issue a software interrupt using int (like int 0) there is no error code to remove

Ratheer than set ESP to 0x2ffff it is preferable in 32-bit code to at least align it on a 4 byte boundary for performance reasons. 0x3000 is evenly divisible by 4.

With a page fault the return address (unless you change it) will point to the instruction that caused the page fault. Your code will enter into an infinite loop trying to do the mov byte [0x6000],'a'  because your page fault handler doesn't attempt to resolve the page fault (ie: it doesn't map a virtual page to a physical page so that the instruction can work.

I missed putting the link to the exception chart listing those exceptions with an error code to remove before doing iret. That can be found here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions . Failure to remove the error code when present will cause the processor to use the error code as a return address and that will likely crash your code.

@MichaelPetch Thank you! The problem is indeed that when a page fault occurs, the cpu pushes an error code onto the stack, and I do not handle this, causing the cpu to point to the wrong place. When I add "add esp,4'', The program becomes normal.

@MichaelPetch Since I did not solve the error in the page fault handler, I executed the iret instruction and returned to the original position and fell into an infinite loop, but this is correct

@MichaelPetch I changed all RET instructions to IRET instructions. There was no problem using int 0xe alone before because the error code was not pushed onto the stack.

@MichaelPetch Thank you again for your enthusiastic answer!
